# replacing dot in string, but leaving last one

Tags: linux

replace the "." [dots], but leave the last one: e.g.: .txt [there could be random number of dots in the string, even zero, i just need the last one]

```
$ echo 'someth.ing.something.txt' | SOMEMAGIC
someth-ing-something.txt
```

Comment: @user564530 - you should accept some of your previous questions to encourage your chances for this question

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'toto.tata.titi.' | sed 's/\.\([^$]\)/-\1/g'
toto-tata-titi.
```

Comment: This only works if the last dot actually is the last character, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'someth.ing.something.txt' | sed 's/\./-/g' | sed 's/-\([^-]*$\)/.\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

basename one.two.three.txt .txt | sed -e 's/.//g' -e 's/$/.txt/'

Answer (score 0):

In sed, with recursive substitutions:

```
sed ':a /\..*\./ {s/\./-/}; t a'
```